# Angularjs directives not binding to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im fighting to get my head around this.

I have a directive which opens a popover with a button in when clicking on a image. This all works as expected, but clicking on the button does not trigger the ng-click Im expecting it to click which leads me to think that its not binding to the DOM.

Here is my code, hope someone can shed some light on this.

```
    <img src="img.png" alt="" custom-popover 
       popover-html="<button ng-click='func()'>
            Click here</button>" popover-placement="bottom" popover-label="Label"/>
```

And here is my directive Im trying to use

```
    app.directive('customPopover', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',     
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {         
                scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
                $(el).popover({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                    placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
                });
            }
         };
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings like this - I don't guarantee it will work since I can't test it.

```
app.directive('customPopover', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',     
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {         
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: $scompile(attrs.popoverHtml)(scope),
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }
     };
 });
```